# How to disable Content Sniffing in php

Tags: php, html, web-applications, http-headers

I want to disable `Content Sniffing` in website. And I don't know how will it be done. The QA Team said that There's no "XContentTypeOptions" HTTP header with the value nosniff set in the response and Content Sniffing is not disable.If someone knows how it will disable than please let me know.
 I want disable `**Content Sniffing**` in my site and i don't know how will I do if someone knows please let me help.
 Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in .htaccess you have to set following rule

```
# prevent mime based attacks
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
```

It prevents the browser from doing MIME-type sniffing. I believe only IE and Chrome/Chromium are enforcing this header for now.
See also : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622941(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can set output headers in PHP using the `header()` function.

`header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

If you want the browser to interpret different resources correctly you may also need to set the content type header too:

`header('Content-Type: <CONTENT-TYPE>');`

Safari doesn't support this feature.
More information about disabling content sniffing:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options